# Passing values from Grid-View inside Modal popup Extender to the text box of parent form

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a form with some text boxes and a button, which when clicked (button), a modalpopup extender will open with values display in grid-view (values from database),

If the user select any row, the name of the selected person must display in the text box of the parent form as shown below;

[image]

I have written this code,

**C# Code:**

```
//GridView inside the Modal popup
 protected void grdPersonDetails_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = grdPersonDetails.SelectedRow;

            Session["testSession"] = row.Cells[0].Text;
            ViewState["testViewState"] = row.Cells[0].Text;
            ChargeFilterModalDialogExtender.Hide();
            txtPersonName.Text = (string) ViewState["sometest"];
            txtPersonName.Text = (string) Session["sometest"];
        }
```

**ASP Code:**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="Server" Text="Person Name:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="Server" ID="txtPersonName" />

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSelectPerson" Text="Select Person" />

 <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ChargeFilterModalDialogExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSelectPerson" CancelControlID="BtnCloseChargeFilterControl" Drag="false" PopupControlID="Dialog_ChargeFilter" Enabled="True" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

    <asp:Button ID="BtnShowDialog" Style="display: none" runat="server" Width="120" Text="Filter Charges" ToolTip="show Chargefilter-Dialog" />

    <asp:Panel ID="Dialog_ChargeFilter" CssClass="modalPopup" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="DialogHeaderFrame" CssClass="DialogHeaderFrame" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="DialogHeader" runat="server" CssClass="DialogHeader" ScrollBars="Auto">
                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LblPopupHeader" runat="server" Text="Charge-Filter" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdGrdCharge" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" ID="BtnCloseChargeFilterControl" Text="close filter" ToolTip="close filter-dialog" CausesValidation="false" Width="150px" runat="server" OnClick="BtnCloseChargeFilterControl_Click" /><br />
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>

                        <td dir="rtl">

                            <asp:GridView ID="grdPersonDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PersonName,PersonEmail" DataSourceID="TempSqlDataSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdPersonDetails_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonName" HeaderText="Person Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PersonName" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonEmail" HeaderText="Person Email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PersonEmail" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Button" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TempSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="select * from person.persons"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**The issue is that when I am selecting a person in the grid-view (inside the modal popup), the selected person name not appear in the related text box in the parent form. (when debugging it, it shows that the value of person name set in the text box)**

Answer (score 1):

Hi Abdul here is a complete demo - tested by me - working 100% successfully.

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"  
        CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ModalPopupExtenderAJAXToolkitWebApp._Default" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
        <style type="text/css">
            .searchButton
            {
                left: 319px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 145px;
                width: 27px;
            }

        </style>
        <link href="Styles/jquery.tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {

               //Hiding Table Available inside div #dvDetails
               // $('#dvDetails').hide();

               /* Binding click event to each imagebutton inside GridView1
                * which is taking value from current row and assigning 
                * to controls inside table
                */
               $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> input[name*='imgbtn']").each(function (index) {
                   $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> input[name*='imgbtn']").bind('click', function (e) {
                       var id = $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*='lblUserId']").text();
                       var username = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtUserName']").val();
                       var firstname = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtFirstName']").val();
                       var lastname = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtLastName']").val();
                       var city = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtCity']").val();
                       var designation = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtDesignation']").val();

                       $('#<%=lblID.ClientID %>').text(id);
                       $('#<%=lblusername.ClientID %>').text(username);
                       $('#<%=txtfname.ClientID %>').val(firstname);
                       $('#<%=txtlname.ClientID %>').val(lastname);
                       $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').val(city);
                       $('#<%=txtDesg.ClientID %>').val(designation);
                   });
               });

               /* Binding click event to each selected radiobutton inside GridView1
               * which is taking value from current row and assigning 
               * to controls inside table
               */

               $('input[value=Remove]').click(function () {
                   $('#dvDetails').show();
                   var id = $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id*='lblUserId']").text();
                   var username = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtUserName']").val();
                   var firstname = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtFirstName']").val();
                   var lastname = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtLastName']").val();
                   var city = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtCity']").val();
                   var designation = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name*='txtDesignation']").val();

                   $('#<%=lblID.ClientID %>').text(id);
                   $('#<%=lblusername.ClientID %>').text(username);
                   $('#<%=txtfname.ClientID %>').val(firstname);
                   $('#<%=txtlname.ClientID %>').val(lastname);
                   $('#<%=txtCity.ClientID %>').val(city);
                   $('#<%=txtDesg.ClientID %>').val(designation);

               });

               var $fieldRevItems = $("#dvDetails");

               $('#<%=btnClose2.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                   $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>').val('');
                   // $fieldRevItems.hide('slow');
                   $fieldRevItems.slideUp(600);
                   e.preventDefault();
               });
           });

        </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <h2>
            Welcome to ASP.NET!
        </h2>

        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div id="dvMain" style="height: 341px; width: 928px">
            <div id="dvFirst">
                Search user Details : <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSearch" CssClass="searchButton" title="Search data for this id"
                ImageUrl="~/search2.jpg" runat="server" OnClick="imgSearch_Click" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup2" runat="server"   Style="display: none" />
                <br />
                <br />

                <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup2"
                PopupControlID="pnlpopup2" CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup2" runat="server" BackColor="Green" Height="269px" Width="600px"
                        Style="display: none; top: 191px;width: 780px;">
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="UserId" 
                                       AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <rowstyle backcolor="#EFF3FB" />
                            <footerstyle backcolor="#507CD1" font-bold="True" forecolor="White" />
                            <pagerstyle backcolor="#2461BF" forecolor="White" horizontalalign="Center" />
                            <headerstyle backcolor="#507CD1" font-bold="True" forecolor="White" />
                            <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="White" />
                            <columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserId">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lblUserId" style="width:100px;" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lblUserId" style="width:100px;" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("City")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("City")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Designation")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" style="width:100px;" CssClass="css2" runat="server"
                                                Text='<%# Eval("Designation")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Close">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSelectUserId" runat="server" Checked="false"  value="Remove"
                                                         AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" 
                                                            />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="~/Edit.jpg" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                      </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <br />
                <br />
             </div>
            <div id="dvDetails">
                <table id="tblDetails" width="30%" style="border: Solid 3px #D55500; height: 100%"
                        cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr style="background-color: #D55500">
                            <td colspan="2" style="height: 10%; color: White; font-weight: bold; font-size: larger"
                                align="center">
                                User Details
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                UserId:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                UserName:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                FirstName:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                LastName:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                City:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="right" style="width: 100%">
                                Designation:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesg" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="center" style="width: 100%">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnClose2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

//====================================================================================
and here is your code behind file.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace ModalPopupExtenderAJAXToolkitWebApp
    {
        public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ToString());
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindGridData();
                }
            }


            protected void BindGridData()
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details", con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                }
            }

            protected DataTable SearchDetails(string id)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details where UserId=@UserId", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId",Convert.ToInt32(id)));
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                return dt;
            }

            protected void imgSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string id = txtSearch.Text;
                if (id != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = SearchDetails(id);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    UpdatePanel1.Update();
                    this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```